# Does anyone have an idea about how to merge 2 arrays in Ionic Storage?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular5

I am getting user input in a 2 step alert and keeping the data separately. I want to merge the arrays like `"www.youtube.com/"+"watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI" = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI"`.

I looked up and found `concat()` but it works like this:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [a,b,c] 
C = A.concat( B ) 
C = [1,2,3,a,b,c]
```

and I want to achieve this: `C = [1,a,2,b,3,c]`

These are emulator screenshots:

[image]

[image]

```
 type: Array<{type: any}> = [];
  myEncodedData: Array<{}> = [];
  extention: Array<{extention: any}> = [];
  testRadioOpen: boolean;
  testRadioResult: any;

    async generateQR(type) {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Create your personalize QR!',
          inputs: [
            {
              name: 'insta',
              type: 'radio',
              label: 'www.instagram.com/',
              value: 'www.instagram.com/',
              checked: type === 'insta'

            },
            {
              name: 'face',
              type: 'radio',
              value: 'www.facebook.com/',
              label: 'www.facebook.com/',
              checked: type === 'face'

            },
            {
              name: 'youtube',
              type: 'radio',
              value: 'www.youtube.com/',
              label: 'www.youtube.com/',
              checked: type === 'youtube'

            },
            {
              name: 'twitter',
              type: 'radio',
              value: 'www.twitter.com/',
              label: 'www.twitter.com/',
              checked: type === 'twitter'

            },
            {
              name: 'empty',
              type: 'radio',
              value: '',
              label: '',
              checked: true
            }
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              cssClass: 'secondary',
              handler: () => {
              }
            }, {
              text: 'Ok',
              handler: async (data) => {
                const alert = await this.alertController.create({
                  header: 'Create your personalize QR!',
                  inputs: [
                    {
                      name: 'extention',
                      type: 'text',
                      placeholder: 'enter an extention: '
                    },
                  ],
                  buttons: [
                    {
                      text: 'Cancel',
                      role: 'cancel',
                      cssClass: 'secondary',
                      handler: () => {
                      }
                    }, {
                      text: 'Ok',
              handler: (data) => {
                console.log('Radio data:', data);
                this.testRadioOpen = false;
                this.testRadioResult = data;
                this.type.push({
                  type: this.testRadioResult,
                });

              }
            }
          ]
        });
                await alert.present();
                this.extention = data;
                this.extention.push({
                  extention: this.testRadioResult,
        });
                this.storage.set('extention', this.extention);
                this.barcodeScanner.encode(this.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, this.extention).then((ReplaceSource) => {
                  console.log(ReplaceSource);
                  this.myEncodedData = ReplaceSource;
                });

      }

    }
         ]
      });
        await alert.present();
      }
```

Comment: You should improve your question, as it is unclear: The code is far from minimal to show what you want to do, and I see no attempt to merge any array in it. Your examples of "concatenation" contradict themselves (arrays merge or strings concatenation?). Also the provided pictures add nothing for us to understand what you want. Yous should rather present clear input example and what output should be. Maybe you should read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want the array as 
"www.youtube.com/"+"watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI" = ["www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI"] 
as you set in your example or as 
"www.youtube.com/"+"watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI" = ["www.youtube.com/","watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI"]

but for the first one you can use .map to achieve that. 
map a, then use index on each loop to get element of b.

```
const a = ['you', 'insta', 'c', 'd'];
const b = ['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4'];

var c = a.map(function (d, i) {
    return d + String(b[i])
})

console.log(c)
// ["youloc1", "instaloc2", "cloc3", "dloc4"]
```

Comment: Pleasure, if it helps, consider marking it as the right answer and upvoting the answer

Comment: Is d represents the last element of the array a in the function part?

Comment: d represents the item stored at the index i of each of the elements in the first array